# Joda ISODateTimeFormat serializing/deserializing

Tags: java, jodatime

When I run the below test, it prints out "2016-11-11". What is going on here? How can I get it print the DateTime string that I supplied as input?

```html
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Adapter2
    extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime>
{


    public DateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return (org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(value));
    }

    public String marshal(DateTime value) {
        return (org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(value));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(new Adapter3().marshal(new Adapter3().unmarshal("2016-11-12T00:00:00.000+08:00")));
    }

}
```

Comment: The test uses Adapter3. You posted the code of Adapter2.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for pointing out. Changing to Adaptor2 also yields the same results. (I am unable to edit my original post to fix this)

Comment: What is the issue exactly? When I run this test, it doesn't print "2016-11-11". It prints 2016-11-11T17:00:00.000+01:00, which is the expected output, given that my timezone is Europe/Paris, which is one hour ahead of UTC. What do you **really** have as output, what do you expect instead, and why?

Comment: My bad, again. The output after the change is "2016-11-11T08:00:00.000-08:00" (in my timezone). What I am hoping to do - is preserve the timezone in the input serialized string, without timezone conversion.

Comment: And the reason I need this, is because I need to perform an action on the date portion of my DateTime input, ignoring the time or timezone. @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.parse()` instead of `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime()`. Or use what `DateTime.parse()` uses:

```
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(value)
```